# How to extract static content and trigger dynamic requests using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract static content(js, css, png) from the response and trigger dynamic http requests with static content.
Can you please let me know if there is any efficient way to extract and pass it http requests.

For example:
From below tags, Need to extract value from src of  tag and store it in list/array and trigger dynamic request based on the number of values.
script asp-add-nonce="true" src="/abc/jquery.js"></script
script asp-add-nonce="true" src="/abc/xyz.min.js?v=skjdfjkdjfdfjlkjlkk"></script

In the above example, we have two values matching the condition, so we need to trigger below two dynamic requests.
If we have 5 tags matching condition, the need to generate and trigger 5 requests in JMeter.
http://appname/abc/jquery.js
http://appname/abc/xyz.min.js?v=skjdfjkdjfdfjlkjlkk

Appreciate if anyone can help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter can automatically parse response and look for images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc.

All you need to do is to tick the relevant box under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)

Alternative option is extracting them using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and run the requests using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) if you need sequential requests or [Parallel Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler) if you need to send the requests at the same moment.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, you are amazing.  By Checking Retrieve all embedded resources, jmeter triggers all dependent static content requests.  In Summary table, it shows only parent request and its response time(Avg, 90th%). Is there any listener using which we can get response time(Avg, 90th%) of each request. This way we can nail down the request which is taking long time.  Any inputs will be helpful

Comment: [Don't use Listeners, they don't add any value and just consume valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/). You should run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl` and the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) will contain each and every individual request. If you like listeners - you can open the .jtl results file in the listener but do this **after** the test.